# Joining 5 tables - 1 master plus 4 with multiple rows to the master but master data is duplicated

Tags: mysql, join, concatenation

I am working in mysql with queries, but I am new to this. I am joining 5 tables where each table has an identifier and one table is the master. Each related table may have more than one associated record to the master table. I am attempting to join these tables but I can't seem to get rid of the duplicated data.

I want all of the related records to be displayed, but I don't want the data in the master table to display for all results in the related tables. I have tried so many different methods but nothing has worked. Currently I have 4 queries that work for the separate tables, but I have not successfully joined them to have the results display the multiple records in the related table but just one record from the master table.

Here are my individual queries that work:

```
SELECT 
    GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.AdditionDescr, 
    GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.BaseArea, 
    GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.Value
FROM 
    GovernmaxExtract 
    INNER JOIN GovernmaxAdditionsExtract 
        ON GovernmaxExtract.mpropertyNumber = GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.PropertyNumber
WHERE (((GovernmaxExtract.mpropertyNumber)="xxx-xxx-xx-xxx"));

SELECT 
    GovernmaxExtract.mpropertyNumber, 
    GovernmaxDwellingExtract.CardNumber, 
    GovernmaxDwellingExtract.MainBuildingType, 
    GovernmaxDwellingExtract.BaseArea
FROM 
    GovernmaxExtract INNER JOIN 
    GovernmaxDwellingExtract ON GovernmaxExtract.mpropertyNumber = GovernmaxDwellingExtract.PropertyNumber
WHERE (((GovernmaxExtract.mpropertyNumber)="xxx-xxx-xx-xxx"));
```

Using these sub queries, I tried to put together 2 of the tables, but now I am getting all records back and it is not reading my input parameter:

```
SELECT GE.mpropertynumber
FROM 
    GovernmaxExtract AS GE, 
    (SELECT 
         GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.AdditionDescr, 
         GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.BaseArea, 
         GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.Value
     FROM GovernmaxExtract INNER JOIN 
         GovernmaxAdditionsExtract ON 
         governmaxextract.mpropertyNumber = GovernmaxAdditionsExtract.PropertyNumber) AS AE
WHERE GE.mpropertynumber = 'xxx-xxx-xx-xxx'
```

I tried nested queries, lots of different joins, and I am just not able to wrap my head around this. I am pretty sure I want to do a nested query since I want the main data from the `Governmax` table to display once with the main data and all records with all info for the associated tables. Maybe I am going about it all wrong.

Our original code was:

```
SELECT 
    ge.*, 
    gde.*, 
    gfe.*, 
    gae.*, 
    goie.* 
FROM governmaxextract AS ge 
    LEFT JOIN governmaxdwellingextract AS gde 
        ON ge.mpropertyNumber = gde.PropertyNumber 
    LEFT JOIN governmaxfeaturesextract AS gfe
        ON gde.PropertyNumber = gfe.PropertyNumber  
    LEFT JOIN governmaxadditionsextract AS gae
        ON gde.PropertyNumber = gae.PropertyNumber  
    RIGHT JOIN governmaxotherimprovementsextract AS goie 
        ON gde.PropertyNumber = goie.PropertyNumber
WHERE ge.mpropertyNumber = '$codeword'   
ORDER BY goie.CardNumber
```

But this gives multiple rows from the master table for each record in the associated tables. I thought about concatenate, but I need the data from the associated tables to be displayed individually. Not sure what to try next. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should see first your tables relationship. Because if you have at least one 1-N relationship you will have duplicated data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, and there is no way to do that like you want. JOIN's can't do that.

I suggest to keep solution with separate queries.

Btw - You could play with UNION operator, 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(SQL)#UNION_operator

P.s.

You could extract main data separately, then extract data from related tables at once using UNION. With UNIOM it will give one result row per each row in related table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to join an two of the Detail tables together without generating duplicate rows, you will have to perform the following operation on each one:

> Group on the foreign key to the Master table, and aggregate all other columns being projected onto the join.

Numeric columns are commonly aggregated with SUM(), COUNT(), MAX(), and MIN(). MAX() and MIN() are also applicable to character data. A PIVOT operation is also sometimes useful as an aggregation operator for this type of circumstance.

Once you have two of the Detail tables grouped and aggregated in this way, they will join without duplicates. Additional Detail tables can be added to the join by first grouping and aggregating them also, in the same fashion.